# How to install latest node inside a docker container

Tags: apt, server, docker, nodejs

How do I install the latest node inside a docker ubuntu 15.10 container?
`apt-get install nodejs` installs version 0.1 and no npm

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve it? For me it installs npm v 3.10, can't get 6+

Answer (score 61):

OK got it,

```
# update 
apt-get update
# install curl 
apt-get install curl
# get install script and pass it to execute: 
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash
# and install node 
apt-get install nodejs
# confirm that it was successful 
node -v
# npm installs automatically 
npm -v
```

Use `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash` for node 5.x

Replace `5` by your desired node version e.g. 8, 12, etc.

Comment: I have seen these same instructions all over the web but I cannot get it to install npm. After running the `apt-get -y install nodejs`, running an npm command does not work. I get `/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found`

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: What if I want to have the exact version as 8.9.4? The above command fails.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions). In the README section it explains how to get different version. Also, 4 is being end-of-lifed, so don't use the above command exactly.

Comment: `/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found` `/bin/sh: apk: command not found` using `FROM amazonlinux:1`

Comment: Since I was using `--no-install-recommends`  I had to manually add `npm` to the install. The following command worked for me: `apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends python build-essential nodejs npm && npm install -g yarn`

Answer (score 42):

Updated solution as of Jan 2019:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
USER root
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY ./package.json /home/app/package.json
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install
```

Comment: but this way you get the latest version 11 of nodejs. what if you want 11.5.4 ?

Comment: Should have down to the minor versions in that deb registry, just replace the X with 5.4 (untested on my side)

Comment: This is not good practice. You will not run it as root!

Answer (score 15):

This is how I have been installing nodeJS into a container. In my case, I am using an nginx base image.

Use the following command

```
    apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq
```

GNUPG is needed by the nodeJS installer. Without it, you will get the following error message;

```
[91mE: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 9):

You can add a single line to your Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:8.2
```

There is a list of supported tag names here: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Comment: This answer doesn't help anyone using a different base image.

Comment: Then they can use Tomasz's answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is my [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) to do this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update
# We directly answer the questions asked using the printf statement
RUN printf 'y\n1\n\1n' | apt install nodejs
RUN apt install -y npm
```

Here we do our docker build:

```
docker build -t mynpm .
```

Here is the version check to verify its success:

```
docker run -it mynpm npm -v
```

The output I get as a result is:
6.14.4

Answer (score 2):

installing nodejs v8 with ubuntu 16.04 base image:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
RUN echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
RUN echo "NODE_ENV=development" >> /etc/environment
RUN more "/etc/environment"
#RUN locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
#RUN dpkg-reconfigure locales

RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get upgrade -y
#RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install curl htop git zip nano ncdu build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev pkg-config glib2.0-dev libexpat1-dev gobject-introspection python-gi-dev apt-transport-https libgirepository1.0-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libgsf-1-dev fail2ban nginx -y

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
RUN npm i -g nodemon
RUN nodemon -v

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y
```

I also installed some extra dependencies I need so you can clean up this code for your needs. But it installs nodejs & npm & nodemon.

Comment: running apt-get upgrade is not a good idea in a container, unless you are ok with very large containers

Comment: @ChadGrant good point, commented out `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

From Node official docker image:

[Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)

[Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/b695e030ea98f272d843feb98ee1ab62943071b3/14/bullseye/Dockerfile):

```
# Install node and npm:
ENV NODE_VERSION 14.18.2

RUN ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
  && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in \
    amd64) ARCH='x64';; \
    ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';; \
    s390x) ARCH='s390x';; \
    arm64) ARCH='arm64';; \
    armhf) ARCH='armv7l';; \
    i386) ARCH='x86';; \
    *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;; \
  esac \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs \
  # smoke tests
  && node --version \
  && npm --version
```

Comment: This is great, because there is no dependency on a 3rd party like nodesource!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two docker images:

```
FROM node:16 AS node_base 
FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY --from=node_base / /
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61054246/10030693

Comment: This also works: `COPY --from=node:18.16.0-slim /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin` if you just want the `node` binary

Comment: Neat tricks. Thanks Gilboot and @veuncent

Answer (score 1):

I am using following Dockerfile to setup node version 8.10.0.

Here I have used **NVM (Node Version Manager )**, so we can choose which node version should be installed on that container. Please use absolute path of npm when installing node modules (eg: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/npm install  leasot@latest -g)

```
   FROM ubuntu:18.04
   ENV NODE_VERSION=8.10.0
   RUN apt-get update && \
       apt-get install wget curl ca-certificates rsync -y
   RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
   ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
   RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
   RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" &&  nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
   RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
   RUN cp /root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/node /usr/bin/
   RUN cp /root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/npm /usr/bin/
   RUN /root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/npm install  leasot@latest -g
```

Note: This is a cropped Dockerfile.